# Reading rows from a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

This code only read ID 1 and I need to read all table. How can I go about this?

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
{
    sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=TOMMY-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Test; Integrated Security=True;";
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Users");
    sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
    adapter.Fill(table);

    if ((string)table.Rows[0]["Name"] == textBox2.Text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Founded");
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop through table.Rows to read the whole table.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    if ((string)table.Rows[i]["Name"] == textBox2.Text)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Founded");
                    }
                } Like this ?

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do here. Probably this could be done using a WHERE condition in your query and there is no need to read the whole table

Comment: Using Linq :                 Boolean founded = table.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(x => x.Field<string>(0) == textBox2.Text).Any();

Comment: Improved grammer and question

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question: you need to do a [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) loop, like this:

```
foreach (var row in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
{
    var name = row["Name"];
    //Continue here
}
```

To explain the use of the `Cast` method:

The `table.Rows` which is of type `DataRowCollection` implements the older [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface which enumerates over the rows but give us the rows as objects of type `object` not `DataRow`. We cast them to `DataRow` by using the [Cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find if a user with a specific name exists or not, then you don't need to read the whole table, but you could write a query that discovers if users with that name exist or not

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
{
    sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "....."";
    sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
    sqlCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Users 
                        WHERE Name = @name";
    sqlConnection.Open();
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
    int result = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());
    if(result > 0) 
        MessageBox.Show("Founded " + result + " user/s");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("No user found with that name");
}
```